# CoqIDE Make on Windows

Tags: windows, coq, coqide

I have [GnuWin32 Make](http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages/make.htm) and [GnuWin32 Coreutils](http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages/coreutils.htm), installed and on my `PATH`. This works:

```
coq_makefile -f _CoqProject -o Makefile.coq
make -f Makefile.coq Frap.vo
```

But if I open `Frap.v` in CoqIDE, and do *Compile > Make*, the only output I see is this:

```
Compilation output:
```

Is this expected? How can I get Coq to build this?

Comment: The compilation output being empty is an outstanding [issue](https://github.com/coq/coq/issues/10519) with CoqIDE.